# Telegram bot v(Python): workflow loop issue

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I've got a task in school to create a Telegram that would give a user some test and then use ChatGPT to give some suggestions. I've decided to give user The Luscher Color Test and then give them music recommendation considering his mood. However it's my first time creating a Telegram Bot and kinda have a huge problem :(
Workflow should look like this:

1. /start command should start conversation from blank page and trigger color selection
2. User has 8 color options, they select colors one after another
3. After all the colors are selected end function is triggered.
4. Color pair interpretations are given to user. Immediately after that user gets two music options: "give me music considering my current mood" // "give me music considering my desired mood"
5. After selection, chatGPT gets prompt and gives answer.

It works just perfect for the first time (right after I "% python bot.py")
However when I go through all the steps and press the /start once again (for the second time) nothing works at all. I don't get any message in console. As if I've ended the conversation for good and can't restart it. I'm sitting here with it for 3 straight days. Got no idea what to fix... Help please(((((

```
from telegram import Update, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, InputMediaPhoto
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackContext, ConversationHandler, CallbackQueryHandler
from openai import OpenAI
from color_interpretations import get_color_pair_interpretation, color_translation

client = OpenAI(api_key="XXXX")

SELECTING_COLOR, MUSIC_OPTIONS, END = range(3)
COLOR_HANDLER, MUSIC_HANDLER = range(10, 12)

def end_conversation(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    print("Ending conversation.")
    # Clear the color selection data
    if COLOR_HANDLER in context.user_data:
        del context.user_data[COLOR_HANDLER]
    return ConversationHandler.END

def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    update.message.reply_text(
        "Hi, I'm Wo! I hope we become friends. I exist for a simple reason - to care about your mental well-being. "
        "I've created a shortened Lüscher test based on information from psychology textbooks to determine your state. "
        "Armed with the best music expert in the world (ChatGPT), I'll try to help you find the perfect song for your mood. "
        "Ready to give it a try? Type /test to start."
    )
    print("/start command received. Resetting user data.")

    context.user_data[COLOR_HANDLER] = {
        'colors': ['Black', 'Blue', 'Brown', 'Green', 'Grey', 'Purple', 'Red', 'Yellow'],
        'selections': [],
    }

    context.user_data['conversation_state'] = None  # Reset the conversation state

    if COLOR_HANDLER in context.user_data and isinstance(context.user_data[COLOR_HANDLER], dict):
        print("Current user data from START FUNCTION:",
              context.user_data[COLOR_HANDLER])

    send_color_images(update, context)
    send_color_keyboard(update, context)
    return SELECTING_COLOR

def send_color_keyboard(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    print("Selected colors inside send_color_keyboard:",
          context.user_data[COLOR_HANDLER]['selections'])
    print("Remaining colors inside send_color_keyboard:",
          context.user_data[COLOR_HANDLER]['colors'])

    remaining_colors = context.user_data[COLOR_HANDLER]['colors']

    if len(remaining_colors) == 1:
        message_text = 'Well, go ahead and click on the last color:'
    else:
        message_text = 'Choose the color that appeals to you the most:'

    keyboard = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton(color_translation[color], callback_data=f'select_color_{color}')] for color in remaining_colors
    ]
    print("Generated Keyboard:", keyboard)

    print("Preparing to send reply with markup.")
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    if update.message:
        print("Replying to REGULAR message.")
        update.message.reply_text(message_text, reply_markup=reply_markup)
        print("Selected colors inside send_color_keyboard:",
              context.user_data[COLOR_HANDLER]['selections'])
        print("Remaining colors inside send_color_keyboard:",
              context.user_data[COLOR_HANDLER]['colors'])
    elif update.callback_query and update.callback_query.message:
        print("Replying to CALLBACK query.")
        update.callback_query.message.reply_text(
            message_text, reply_markup=reply_markup)
        print("Selected colors inside send_color_keyboard:",
              context.user_data[COLOR_HANDLER]['selections'])
        print("Remaining colors inside send_color_keyboard:",
              context.user_data[COLOR_HANDLER]['colors'])

def send_color_images(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    media_group = []

    for color in context.user_data[COLOR_HANDLER]['colors']:
        image_path = f'images/{color.lower()}.jpg'
        media_group.append(InputMediaPhoto(open(image_path, 'rb')))

    context.user_data[COLOR_HANDLER]['media_group'] = media_group

    if media_group:
        context.bot.send_media_group(
            chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, media=media_group)

def send_color_image(update: Update, context: CallbackContext, color: str):
    image_path = f'images/{color.lower()}.jpg'
    context.bot.send_photo(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
                           photo=open(image_path, 'rb'))

def save_selection(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    user_selection = update.callback_query.data
    print("User selection:", user_selection)

    print("Current user data from SAVE_SELECTION:",
          context.user_data[COLOR_HANDLER])
    print("Remaining colors:", context.user_data[COLOR_HANDLER]['colors'])
    print("Selected colors inside save_selection:",
          context.user_data[COLOR_HANDLER]['selections'])

    if user_selection.startswith('select_color_'):
        selected_color = user_selection.replace('select_color_', '')

        if selected_color in context.user_data[COLOR_HANDLER]['colors']:
            context.user_data[COLOR_HANDLER]['selections'].append(
                selected_color)
            context.user_data[COLOR_HANDLER]['colors'].remove(selected_color)
        else:
            print(f"Error: {selected_color} is not in the list.")

        send_color_images(update, context)

        if context.user_data[COLOR_HANDLER]['colors']:
            print("Colors remaining. Sending new color keyboard.")
            send_color_keyboard(update, context)
            print("Returning SELECTING_COLOR.")
            return SELECTING_COLOR
        else:
            print("All color selections done. Proceeding to END.")
            return end(update, context)

    print("Invalid user selection. Returning SELECTING_COLOR.")
    return SELECTING_COLOR

def end(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    print("END FUNCTION TRIGGERED")

    desired_mood = interpret_colors(
        context.user_data[COLOR_HANDLER]['selections'][:2])
    current_mood = interpret_colors(
        context.user_data[COLOR_HANDLER]['selections'][2:4])
    indifferent_mood = interpret_colors(
        context.user_data[COLOR_HANDLER]['selections'][4:6])
    avoid_mood = interpret_colors(
        context.user_data[COLOR_HANDLER]['selections'][6:])

    interpretation_message = (
        f"Thank you for taking the test! Based on the order of color choices, I can roughly describe your state as follows:\n"
        f"\n"
        f"1️⃣ Subconscious direction in feelings: {desired_mood}\n"
        f"2️⃣ Your current state: {current_mood}\n"
        f"3️⃣ Mood that you are currently indifferent to: {indifferent_mood}\n"
        f"4️⃣ Undesirable state right now: {avoid_mood}"
    )

    if update.message:
        update.message.reply_text(interpretation_message)
    elif update.callback_query and update.callback_query.message:
        update.callback_query.message.reply_text(interpretation_message)
    else:
        print(interpretation_message)

    return music_options(update, context)

def interpret_colors(color_list):
    interpretation = []
    color_pairs = [color_list[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(color_list), 2)]

    for colors in color_pairs:
        interpretation.append(get_color_pair_interpretation(colors))

    return ', '.join(interpretation)

def music_options(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    keyboard = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton(
            "❇️ Help me enhance my current mood", callback_data='current_mood')],
        [InlineKeyboardButton(
            "✳️ I want to achieve a desired mood", callback_data='desired_mood')],
    ]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    if update.message:
        print("IT'S IF")
        update.message.reply_text(
            'What would you like from the music right now?', reply_markup=reply_markup)
    elif update.callback_query and update.callback_query.message:
        print("IT'S ELIF")
        update.callback_query.message.reply_text(
            'What would you like from the music right now?', reply_markup=reply_markup)

    return MUSIC_OPTIONS

def suggest_music(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    message_text = 'Looking for the best music for you. Please wait a moment...'
    print("suggest_music function called.")

    if update.effective_message:
        update.effective_message.reply_text(message_text)
    else:
        context.bot.send_message(
            update.callback_query.message.chat_id, text=message_text)

    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    option = query.data

    desired_mood = interpret_colors(
        context.user_data[COLOR_HANDLER]['selections'][:2])
    current_mood = interpret_colors(
        context.user_data[COLOR_HANDLER]['selections'][2:4])

    if option == 'current_mood':
        prompt = f"I would like the music to help me enhance my current mood. My current mood: {current_mood}. Please provide links to Youtube where this is possible"
        suggested_music = get_music_suggestion(prompt)
        query.message.reply_text(suggested_music)
    elif option == 'desired_mood':
        prompt = f"I really want to achieve my desired mood through music. My desired mood: {desired_mood}. My current mood: {current_mood}. Please provide links to Youtube where this is possible"
        suggested_music = get_music_suggestion(prompt)
        query.message.reply_text(suggested_music)

    return end_conversation(update, context)

def get_music_suggestion(prompt):
    print("Prompt for music suggestion:", prompt)
    response = client.chat.completions.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=[
            {"role": "system", "content": "You are a very knowledgeable person in different types of music"},
            {"role": "user", "content": prompt}
        ]
    )

    return response.choices[0].message.content

def main() -> None:
    updater = Updater(
        'XXXZZ', use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.user_data.clear()

    color_selection_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start)],
        states={
            SELECTING_COLOR: [CallbackQueryHandler(save_selection)],
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('end_conversation', end_conversation)],
        name="color_selection_handler",
    )

    music_options_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CallbackQueryHandler(suggest_music)],
        states={
            MUSIC_OPTIONS: [CallbackQueryHandler(suggest_music)],
        },
        fallbacks=[
            CommandHandler('end_conversation', end_conversation),
            ConversationHandler.END,
        ],
        name="music_options_handler",
    )

    dp.add_handler(color_selection_handler)
    dp.add_handler(music_options_handler)

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```